# How to fill out w4 for multiple jobs?

Tags: income-tax

I just started a 2nd job and want to make sure I have the proper amount of taxes withheld. The first jobs pays $30 an hour ($62,500 annually, although with the amount of overtime I work I'm actually closer to $90k). Second one pays $17 an hour ($35,360 annually). Question is how do I fill out the second one and do I have to go back and fill in anything on the first job. I would rather not let the hr at my first job know that I have a second job, but I'm not sure if I can do that and have enough tax withheld

Comment: There are multiple reasons to require greater withholding than normal (dual income household, capital gains, ...), so your first company likely won't bat an eye at changing your withholding. Beyond that, take last year's numbers and see what happens when the second job is added - it likely will require additional withholding because it will be taxed at a higher incremental rate.

Answer (score 2):

The IRS instructions for the [W-4](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf) includes the line:

> Multiple jobs. Complete Steps 3 through 4(b) on only one Form W-4.
> Withholding will be most accurate if you do this on the Form W-4 for
> the highest paying job

You will get the most accurate results if you modify the form for the higher paying job.

Some employers accept paper forms. Other have a web interface. Because there can be many reasons for tweaking a W-4 besides it generally isn't a concern. When the w-4 is updated via a web interface it is likely that HR would not even notice the change.

I have had non-standard numbers in my W-4 for decades. They were to adjust for my spouse working. Changes to the way were were saving for retirement. Converting traditional IRA to Roth IRA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell them you have another job. You can either fill out "Other Income (not from jobs)" or add "Extra Withholding" to have a specific extra amount withheld each paycheck.

There are several calculators online that can estimate your total tax due based on your total income, dependents, and deductions. Use that to estimate how much should be withheld each month and make sure you are reasonably close to that.

If you are unsure (and can afford the reduced cash flow) it's better to withhold slightly more that needed to avoid underpayment, both because of the possible penalty and the impact of a large tax bill.  As long as you withhold more than you did last year, 90%  or your tax due this year, or are within 1,000 of your total tax due, there will be no penalty.